# Site for posting project so people can use it and help make it better

Tags: python

I know this is a weird question and I don't know if I'm allowed to ask this here or not. If not feel free to delete this post. But is there a feature on this site or some other site where I'm able to post my project I'm working on so other people could use it and together try to improve it?

Comment: so basically github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably is Open Source community. The best way to achieve that is using something like Github, where you can make your project available as a repository and share for other people to contribute.

This link might help you: https://github.com/open-source

Anyways, I suggest you upload your project to Github if you're thinking about making it public, that is one of the best ways to show your projects on job interviews or as a portfolio.

Comment: alright this is kinda what I meant yeah, maybe thought there was something else